# How to access "name" in nested array of dictionary

Tags: json, swift

Below is a code to parse a JSON data from the news API. How do I access "name" in the source section of array without using the codable protocol  ? This how the json data looks like when retrieved from the website.

```
[{
    author = "Louise Matsakis";
    content = "When the novelcoronavirus was first discovered in China last winter, the country responded aggressively, placing tens of millions of people into strict lockdown. As Covid-19 spread from Wuhan to the \U2026 [+3647 chars]";
    description = "In China, the messaging platform blocked thousands of keywords related to the virus, a new report reveals.";
    publishedAt = "2020-08-27T21:30:00Z";
    source =     {
        id = wired;
        name = Wired;
    };
    title = "How WeChat Censored the Coronavirus Pandemic";
    url = "https://www.wired.com/story/wechat-chinese-internet-censorship-coronavirus/";
    urlToImage = "https://media.wired.com/photos/5f46ababa73ba18581f3aac0/191:100/w_1280,c_limit/Security_China_1228043332.jpg";
}, {
    author = "Kate Dore on Two Cents, shared by Kate Dore to Lifehacker";
    content = "As college students return to school, some have noticed a new line item on their bill: a coronavirus fee. With new costs for screening, testing, and safety configurations, the New York Times reports \U2026 [+1857 chars]";
    description = "As college students return to school, some have noticed a new line item on their bill: a coronavirus fee. With new costs for screening, testing, and safety configurations, the New York Times reports some colleges and universities are passing part of the expen\U2026";
    publishedAt = "2020-08-17T20:00:00Z";
    source =     {
        id = "<null>";
        name = "Lifehacker.com";
    };
    title = "What to Know About Coronavirus Charges on Your College Bill";
    url = "https://twocents.lifehacker.com/what-to-know-about-coronavirus-charges-on-your-college-1844752829";
    urlToImage = "https://i.kinja-img.com/gawker-media/image/upload/c_fill,f_auto,fl_progressive,g_center,h_675,pg_1,q_80,w_1200/zeeqev5k6mmyauyqlfx8.jpg";
}, {
    author = "Jason DeParle";
    content = "Money helps children in part because of what it buys food, housing, better schools, health care and summer camps. But it also important in a less obvious way: It reduces stress, which can reach toxic\U2026 [+2508 chars]";
    description = "The virus doesn\U2019t sicken kids as much as adults. But it can still destroy their futures. A child allowance would help.";
    publishedAt = "2020-08-22T18:55:36Z";
    source =     {
        id = "<null>";
        name = "New York Times";
    };
    title = "The Coronavirus Generation";
    url = "https://www.nytimes.com/2020/08/22/sunday-review/coronavirus-poverty-child-allowance.html";
    urlToImage = "https://static01.nyt.com/images/2020/08/23/opinion/sunday/21Deparle/21Deparle-facebookJumbo.jpg";
}, 
func parseData(data:Data)-> [Articles]   {
     var articles: [Articles]? = [] // holds parsed data

        do {
            let jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as? NSDictionary
            
            let jsonArticles = jsonResult?["articles"] as? [AnyObject] ?? [] // gets first head of json file and dteremines weather
          
            for jsonArticle in jsonArticles{ // captures data and converts to article type
         let article = Articles()
         article.author = jsonArticle["author"] as? String
         article.title = jsonArticle["description"] as? String
         article.publishedAt = jsonArticle["publishedAt"] as? String
         articles?.append(article) //put article data in the array
            }
```

Comment: could you format the json you're getting back properly?  you should be able to do something like `jsonArticle["source"] as? [Any: Any]` and continue parsing through the dictionary as you were with the previous articles

Comment: Any reason why you can't use `JSONDecoder`?  Also, might be more helpful to post the actual JSON

Comment: Btw what you posted is not a JSON but a PropertyList.

Comment: I just posted the actual json format

Comment: @MayowaPaul Please compare a [JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#Example) with a [PropertyList](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Property_list#NeXTSTEP). I'm not saying you can't decode it your way but this is definitely not a JSON.

Comment: @MayowaPaul Take what you've posted and put into [JSON Formatter & Validator](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com)

Comment: @pawello2222 I thought a plist was more like XML...but in any case, it's not JSON, looks more like a `print` a `Map`/`Dictionary`

Comment: @MayowaPaul Where's the source of this data?  How are you getting it?

Comment: @MadProgrammer  It is a plist but a macOS version and JSON-compatible. Wikipedia has actually a pretty good explanation: *While macOS can also read the NeXTSTEP format, Apple sets it aside in favor of two new formats of its own, one XML-based and the other binary. Apple also has a partially-compatible JSON format (NSJSONSerialization).*

Comment: @pawello2222 Ah, sweet

Comment: its not a plist file. This is directly from the news API.

Comment: @MayowaPaul Which News API?

Comment: https://newsapi.org this one

Answer (score 1):

So, lets start with, the "example source" is not JSON, so I re-formatted so it could actually be parsed

```
[
    {
        "author":"Louise Matsakis",
        "content":"When the novelcoronavirus was first discovered in China last winter, the country responded aggressively, placing tens of millions of people into strict lockdown. As Covid-19 spread from Wuhan to the \\U2026 [+3647 chars]",
        "description":"In China, the messaging platform blocked thousands of keywords related to the virus, a new report reveals.",
        "publishedAt":"2020-08-27T21:30:00Z",
        "source":{
            "id":"wired",
            "name":"Wired"
        },
        "title":"How WeChat Censored the Coronavirus Pandemic",
        "url":"https://www.wired.com/story/wechat-chinese-internet-censorship-coronavirus/",
        "urlToImage":"https://media.wired.com/photos/5f46ababa73ba18581f3aac0/191:100/w_1280,c_limit/Security_China_1228043332.jpg"
    }
]
```

Then using Playground, I built a series of structures which represented the JSON structure, conforming them to `Decodable` to make it easier to parse the JSON

```
struct Source: Decodable {
    let id: String
    let name: String
}

struct Article: Decodable {
    let author: String
    let content: String
    let description: String
    let publishedAt: Date
    let source: Source
    let title: String
    let url: URL
    let urlToImage: URL
}
```

I then used Swift's `JSONDecoder` to parse the content

```
let source = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Source", withExtension: "json")!
do {
    let data = try Data(contentsOf: source)
    let decoder  = JSONDecoder()
    decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .iso8601
    let articles = try decoder.decode([Article].self, from: data)
    
    for article in articles {
        print(article.source.name)
    }
    
} catch let error {
    print("\(error)")
}
```

And this will then print `Wired`

## Follow up...

> its not a plist file. This is directly from the news API.

Okay, after a little bit of Googling, you seem to mean `newsapi.org`

So, after a little test using...

```
    let url = URL(string: "https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=au&apiKey=...")!
    let task = URLSession.shared.downloadTask(with: url) { localURL, urlResponse, error in
        print("\(error)")
        if let localURL = localURL {
            if let string = try? String(contentsOf: localURL) {
                print(string)
            }
        }
    }
```

I was able to get the following response...

```
{
    "status":"ok",
    "totalResults":38,
    "articles":[
        {
            "source":{
                "id":null,
                "name":"News-Medical.Net"
            },
            "author":null,
            "title":"Host tissue T cells play a previously unappreciated role in acute graft-versus-host disease - News-Medical.net",
            "description":"Allogenic hematopoietic stem cell transplantation (HSCT) is a procedure that infuses a donor's healthy blood-forming stem cells into a recipient as part of a potentially curative therapy for cancer.",
            "url":"https://www.news-medical.net/news/20200828/Host-tissue-T-cells-play-a-previously-unappreciated-role-in-acute-graft-versus-host-disease.aspx",
            "urlToImage":"https://www.news-medical.net/image.axd?picture=2014%2f7%2fChemo_Vials-620x480.jpg",
            "publishedAt":"2020-08-29T02:28:00Z",
            "content":"Reviewed by Emily Henderson, B.Sc.Aug 28 2020\r\nAllogenic hematopoietic stem cell transplantation (HSCT) is a procedure that infuses a donor's healthy blood-forming stem cells into a recipient as part… [+3762 chars]"
        },
        {
            "source":{
                "id":"abc-news-au",
                "name":"ABC News (AU)"
            },
            "author":"ABC News",
            "title":"Black Panther actor Chadwick Boseman dies of cancer - ABC News",
            "description":"Actor Chadwick Boseman, who played black icons Jackie Robinson and James Brown before finding fame as the regal Black Panther in the Marvel cinematic universe, dies of cancer.",
            "url":"https://www.abc.net.au/news/2020-08-29/chadwick-boseman,-black-panther-actor,-dies-of-cancer/12609278",
            "urlToImage":"https://www.abc.net.au/cm/rimage/12609312-16x9-large.jpg?v=2",
            "publishedAt":"2020-08-29T02:14:00Z",
            "content":"Actor Chadwick Boseman, who played black icons Jackie Robinson and James Brown before finding fame as the regal Black Panther in the Marvel cinematic universe, has died of cancer.\r\nHe was 42.\r\nBosema… [+651 chars]"
        },
        {
            "source":{
                "id":"abc-news-au",
                "name":"ABC News (AU)"
            },
            "author":"ABC News",
            "title":"Queensland records four more coronavirus cases - ABC News",
            "description":"Health Minister Steven Miles says Queensland has recorded four more cases of COVID-19 as a result of testing from the previous 24-hour period.",
            "url":"https://www.abc.net.au/news/2020-08-29/four-more-case-of-coronavirus-queensland/12607350",
            "urlToImage":"https://www.abc.net.au/cm/rimage/12159214-16x9-large.jpg?v=2",
            "publishedAt":"2020-08-29T01:57:00Z",
            "content":"Queensland has recorded four new cases of coronavirus as a result of testing in the past 24 hours. \r\nHealth Minister Steven Miles said all four cases were related to the known COVID-19 outbreak at th… [+2394 chars]"
        },
        // More results
    ]
}
```

And, that looks familiar.

So, I modified the code from above to...

```
struct Source: Decodable {
    let id: String?
    let name: String
}

struct Article: Decodable {
    let author: String?
    let content: String?
    let description: String
    let publishedAt: Date
    let source: Source
    let title: String
    let url: URL
    let urlToImage: URL?
}

struct NewsAPIResponse: Decodable {
    let status: String
    let totalResults: Int
    let articles: [Article]
}
```

And then used ...

```
do {
    let url = URL(string: "https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=au&apiKey=df4df715a25e4f8797914f036d2da5ec")!
    let data = try Data(contentsOf: url)
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .iso8601
    
    let response = try decoder.decode(NewsAPIResponse.self, from: data)
    
    for article in response.articles {
        print(article.source.name)
    }
} catch let error {
    print(error)
}
```

to download and parse it.

I can then access the source via the `source` property of the `Article`, simple.

Comment: You may want to take a look at PropertyListDecoder. It should be able to decode OP's input file (however badly formatted).

Comment: @pawello2222 Why can't Apple just do things simply 

Comment: @pawello2222 Okay, just tried `PropertyListDecoder` and it failed - but I was using a iOS playground.  I also tried a macOS playground and still get `The given data was not a valid property list`